# Pandas: from adjacency matrix to series of node lists

Tags: python, pandas, discrete-mathematics, data-transform

I have which I think is a pretty general problem. Namely, to recast a bipartite adjacency matrix in a list of a list of nodes. In Pandas, that would mean transform from a specific `pd.DataFrame` format to a specific `pd.Series` format.

For non discrete-math people, this looks like the following transformation:

From

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['item1','item2','item3'],
                  index=['foo','bar','qux'], 
                  data = [[1,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,0,0]])
```

which looks like

```
    item1   item2   item3
foo     1       1       0
bar     0       1       1
qux     0       0       0
```

To

```
srs = pd.Series([['item1','item2'],['item2','item3'],[]],index=['foo','bar','qux'])
```

that looks like

```
foo    [item1, item2]
bar    [item2, item3]
qux                []
dtype: object
```

I have partially achieved this goal with the following code:

```
df_1 = df.stack().reset_index()

srs = df_1.loc[df_1[0]==1].groupby('level_0')['level_1'].apply(list)
```

which, together with being slightly unreadable, has the issue of having dropped poor `qux` along the way.

Is there any shorter path to the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want avoid reshape by `stack` and `groupby` here is possible use list comprehension with convert `0,1` to boolean by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and then filter columns names, last pass it to `Series` constructor:

```
print([list(df.columns[x]) for x in df.astype(bool).to_numpy()])
[['item1', 'item2'], ['item2', 'item3'], []]

s = pd.Series([list(df.columns[x]) for x in df.astype(bool).to_numpy()], index=df.index)
print(s)
foo    [item1, item2]
bar    [item2, item3]
qux                []
dtype: object
```

If also performance is important use:

```
c = df.columns.to_numpy()
s = pd.Series([list(c[x]) for x in df.astype(bool).to_numpy()], index=df.index)
```

Comment: Very cool, it uses a completely different logic than stack and groupby...

Answer (score 1):

Applying straightforward list comprehension on each row (`axis=1`) can work. If there are no non-zero elements in the row, an empty list will be produced.

```
df.apply(lambda row: [df.columns[i] for i, el in enumerate(row) if el], axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
foo    [item1, item2]
bar    [item2, item3]
qux                []
dtype: object
```